# SqlDependency fire correctly, but also at start time

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, notifications, sqldependency

I'm getting some troubles in the last days to use the SQL Dependency.

With the sample in [this link](http://jgowdy.blogspot.it/2010/01/sqldependency-query-notification-with.html) I have ALMOST reach my goal. "Almost" because the event get fired correctly, but also at the startup, when I call the Start method of the MyService class. Here there is my code, but as you can see it's the same (or almost) of the link.

I think I can simply insert a bool value, only to avoid the initialitation event, but I think also that another solution would be better.

SQLWatcher:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public enum SqlWatcherNotificationType
{
    Blocking,
    Threaded // Launch in another thread so SqlWatcher can immediately start monitoring again.
}

public class SqlWatcher : IDisposable
{
    private string ConnectionString;
    private SqlConnection Connection;
    private SqlCommand Command;
    private SqlDataAdapter Adapter;
    private DataSet Result;
    private SqlWatcherNotificationType NotificationType;

    public SqlWatcher(string ConnectionString, SqlCommand Command, SqlWatcherNotificationType NotificationType)
    {
        this.NotificationType = NotificationType;
        this.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        SqlDependency.Start(this.ConnectionString);
        this.Connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        this.Connection.Open();
        this.Command = Command;
        this.Command.Connection = this.Connection;
        Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this.Command);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        RegisterForChanges();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(this.ConnectionString);
    }

    public delegate void SqlWatcherEventHandler(DataSet Result);

    public event SqlWatcherEventHandler OnChange;

    public DataSet DataSet
    {
        get { return Result; }
    }

    private void RegisterForChanges()
    {
        //Remove old dependency object
        this.Command.Notification = null;
        //Create new dependency object
        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(this.Command);
        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(Handle_OnChange);
        //Save data
        Result = new DataSet();
        Adapter.Fill(Result);
        //Notify client of change to DataSet
        switch (NotificationType)
        {
            case SqlWatcherNotificationType.Blocking:
                OnChange(Result);
                break;
            case SqlWatcherNotificationType.Threaded:
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ChangeEventWrapper, Result);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeEventWrapper(object state)
    {
        DataSet Result = (DataSet)state;
        OnChange(Result);
    }

    private void Handle_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type != SqlNotificationType.Change)
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to create queue notification subscription!");

        //Clean up the old notification
        SqlDependency dep = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dep.OnChange -= Handle_OnChange;

        //Register for the new notification
        RegisterForChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stop();
    }
}
```

and this is MyService class:

```
public class MyService
{
    private static SqlWatcher SqlQueueWatcher;

    public static void Start()
    {
        string connS = MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=111;";
        //Build the command object we want to monitor (don't include a SqlConnection)
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CODVEI FROM dbo.ArchivioErogazioni");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //Setup the SQLWatcher
        SqlQueueWatcher = new SqlWatcher(connS, cmd, SqlWatcherNotificationType.Blocking);
        SqlQueueWatcher.OnChange += new SqlWatcher.SqlWatcherEventHandler(QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange);
        SqlQueueWatcher.Start();
    }

    private static void QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange(DataSet Result)
    {
        //Do something with the updated DataSet object
        Debug.WriteLine("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");  ---> ENTERS HERE IN THE INIT PHASE
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        SqlQueueWatcher.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and this is how I symply call it:

```
MyService.Start();
```

Is the bool flag a bad idea? Why does it enter in QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange at startup time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need only to set the notification for that `SqlCommand` to null.

```
 cmd.Notification = null;
```

Just try this and i think your problem will be resolved. Enter this line before starting the dependency using the `SqlWatcher` class